# what does "tax write-off" mean?

Tags: idioms, sentence-meaning

can someone tell me what does "a tax write-off" and also "consigned to specialty sections" mean in the following text:

> Stephen Thomas Erlewine wrote that prior to Nirvana, "alternative
>   music was consigned to specialty sections of record stores, and major
>   labels considered it to be, at the very most, a tax write-off".

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(band)#Legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, a *tax write-off* is any legitimate expense that can be deducted from your taxable income, when you file your tax returns.

Also, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-off#Income_tax):

> In income tax calculation, a write-off is the itemized deduction of an
>   item's value from a person's taxable income. Thus, if a person in the
>   United States has a taxable income of $50,000 per year, a $100
>   telephone for business use would lower the taxable income to $49,900.
>   If that person is in a 25% tax bracket, the tax due would be lowered
>   by $25. Thus the net cost of the telephone is $75 instead of $100.

And as for *consigned to specialty sections of record stores*, the most probable meaning is that prior to Nirvana and it's immense success, any form of alternate music was not in great demand and, as such, was usually placed only in the *specials section* of record stores, away from the (then) mainstream music, if you will.